# Repaint issues in WebKit browsers when positioning SVG elements with JavaScript events

Tags: javascript, webkit, svg

I have a custom SVG control I've created which consists of a time line representing 32 hours (24 hours from the current day plus 8 hours from the previous day). There's two sliders overlayed on the time line which can be dragged around to set the starting time and ending time, between which data is shown else where in the web app.

The SVG and JavaScript are both pretty lengthy and complicated, so I'll just post the basic structure for now. I'll post more details if requested. The SVG contains nested SVG elements and gets a little crazy, but it looks something like this:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
    <svg id="TimeLineAdjust" x="1.5%" width="97%" overflow="visible">
        "Some static stuff that draws out the time line..."
    </svg>
    <svg id="TimesContainer" x="1.5%" y="0" width="97%" height="100%" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision">
        "Various labels and buttons and such..."
        <text id="StartLabel"></text>
        <text id="EndLabel"></text>
        <text id="DurationLabel"></text>
    </svg>
    <svg id="TimeSlider" y="0" height="100%" overflow="visible">
        <defs>
            <polygon id="DefMarker" points="-0.5,77.5 -0.5,23.5 9.5,23.5 9.5,32.5 0.5,41.5 0.5,77.5" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:1" />
        </defs>

        <rect id="SliderRect" x="0%" y="41.5" width="100%" height="36" style="stroke:none;opacity:0.5;fill:rgb(0,0,255)" />
        <use id="SliderStartLine" x="0%" transform="scale(-1,1)" xlink:href="#DefMarker" />
        <use id="SliderEndLine" x="100%" xlink:href="#DefMarker" />
    </svg>
</svg>
```

Now when you mousedown on either "SliderRect", "SliderStartLine", or "SliderEndLine" I hook onto the mousemove event and use it to determine what to set the start time, end time, and duration variables else where in my JavaScript. Then I call another function which positions "TimeSlider" accordingly. It looks like this:

```
TimeSlider.setAttribute('x', newXVal);
TimeSlider.setAttribute('width', newWidthVal);

StartLabel.textContent = newStartVal;
EndLabel.textContent = newEndVal;
DurationLabel.textContent = newDurationVal;
```

This all works perfectly, so don't worry about those values that I'm assigning, they're correct. The only problem is that as the new positions are painted onto the screen, the old ones are "ghosting" across the screen, and they stay there until the mouseup event is fired. Also, SliderRect does not rescale to 100% of TimeSlider when it's width is changed. I was able to fix this issue with:

```
SliderRect.setAttribute('width', '100%');
```

But this shouldn't be necessary. Both of these issues only happen on Chrome/Win7 and Safari/Win7. It does not happen in IE9/FF9/Opera.

Any ideas?

Edit: Also, I've noticed that there's no ghosting when dragging "SliderEndLine". Only when dragging "SliderRect" or "SliderStartLine", which would lead one to believe that the problem must be with "TimeSlider.setAttribute('x', newXVal);"

Comment: Sounds like you should file a bug at http://bugs.webkit.org.

Comment: @ErikDahlström You're right. Turns out the 'ghosting' bug is actually already fixed in latest WebKit, it's just a matter of time before it's pushed out in Chrome and Safari. The 'rect' resizing issue is not known though so I have to submit it as a bug.